# Influence of the degenerate Delaunay tiles on the Voronoï diagram

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, triangulations

About three or four years ago, I implemented the Delaunay and Voronoi tessellations in [Haskell](https://github.com/stla/qhull), with the help of the **Qhull** C library. Now I reimplement it in R.

I have noticed that including or not the degenerate tiles of the Delaunay tessellation has a serious influence on the Voronoï tessellation obtained by duality.

For example, this is the Voronoï diagram (restricted to its bounded cells) of a dodecahedron surrounded by three pairwise perpendicular dashed circles, when I include the degenerate Delaunay tiles:

[image]

And here is the result when I don't include the degenerate tiles:

[image]

How can one explain this difference?

---

## EDIT

Here is a picture of the object from which I take the Delaunay tessellation, except this is a dodecahedron instead of a tetrahedron:

[image]